# Rails cant find url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, get

I have this in my routes

```
match '/users/sign_up/name/:name/email/:email/password/:password', :to => 'registrations#urlUserCreate'
```

when i say this

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up/name/myname/email/jaja@jaja.ja/password/kevin1
```

it tells me

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_up/name/myname/email/jaja@jaja.ja/password/kevin1"
```

Why is it doing this. (I didn't post my controller because i think that it would tell me if the problem is there, i keep modifying it and it doesn't change anything, same error), a part of thinks that the "@" symbol or the "." in the email is causing this

Comment: Sending the password in a GET parameter is insecure, in a route fragment - even more so.

Comment: It's not even a GET parameter here, it's part of the URN, which is even more wrong and a total violation of REST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to RFC 1738 (URL), the "@" sign is a reserved character and should not be used as you do. It is usually used for a username:password@host combination in the scheme.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738

This is the reason why it fails.